# Resize ScrollView based on TableView size

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview

I'm trying to create layout that it structured like this:

```
 - View 
   -- ScrollView
       --- ContentView
            ---- CustomView
            ---- CustomView
            ---- TableView
            ---- CustomView
```

The `tableView` itself is auto-resizable using "invalidateIntrinsicContentSize" and when I add items - the height of the `tableview` changes, pushing the custom view below it further down.

Once enough items are added I the bottom custom view is hidden and the scroll doesn't work.

important fact - the bottom custom view doesn't have a bottom constraint. It is pushed down by the it's top constraint to the `tableView`.

If I do set a bottom constraint - the table view will no longer be dynamically resized.

The intended behaviour:
When a user adds items to the list and the list gets too big the ContentView will be scrollable so the user can scroll to see the bottom `view`.

The actual behaviour: 
When a user adds items to the list and the list gets too big, the bottom view is pushed down and outside of sight and content is not scrollable.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I think what is happening.

Since you are using `UITableView`, it has its own scroll view. So when the `UITableView` list gets too big, UITableView itself becomes scrollable rather than ScrollView's contentView becoming scrollable.

To achieve what you need, you would have to make the `UITableView` not scrollable and use the `intrinsicHeight` of the `UITableView` to get the actual height of `UITableView` along with all the items. If you have items with varying heights, it will be a problem because you won't know the height before rendering. With same height for all the rows, you can get the total height of the `UITableView` and set the height constraint to that value. This will increase the `contentSize` of the outer `ScrollView`, making it scrollable.

Apart from `UITableView`, you can also use `UIStackView`. This is because you are not using the reusing capabilities of `UITableView` anyways. Managing the `datasource` and `delegates` should not be a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for the overview and information. That helped me understand it better and fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constraint for tableview height, And take its reference to your swift file, by dragging it as you take other views. Now in your code, Just do this

```
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableViewNoOfItems * tableViewCellHeight;
```

if you have set other constraints perfectly inside scrollview, It should work perfectly. Means `TableView` should have `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` margined constraints from the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
        tblViewHeight.constant = CGFloat( tableview row count * 45 ) 
        var size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        if size.height < scrollView.frame.size.height
         {
            size = scrollView.frame.size
        }
        contenViewHeight.constant = size.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
        scrollView.contentSize.height = contenViewHeight.constant
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you could do is:

1. Disable tableView's scroll `tableView.isScrollEnabled = false`
2. Every time a user adds items to the list, reload the tableView

Also using UIStackView with vertical axis and `.fillEqually` distribution as a Content View would be much more convenient as you won't need to set any positional constraints to your views, but may need to set height constraints if intrinsic content size can't be determined by the engine